# Testing an Action for Google Home post production deploy

Tags: actions-on-google

We've effectively rolled out a production release on Google Home and subsequently generated a new test release. Unfortunately, we're facing an issue where the test version isn't visible in both the Google Home and Google Assistant apps. Prior to the production release, we could locate the action with [Test] in the name through the app, but it seems to have vanished since then.

Is anyone familiar with this issue or aware of what might be causing it?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we have developed a "Smart Home" action which does not support these different channels. Google says to create a new test project to test any changes.